# Get Google Analytics data when custom dimension doesn't exist

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a Python script using the Reporting API v4. In the reports I'm trying to get, there is each time a custom dimension (sometimes even 2). Because of that, I don't have any data when this custom dimension is empty (and also before this custom dimension was created). Using the Google Analytics UI, if I do the dimensions drill down putting the custom dimension last, then I do get all data but I don't if I put the custom dimension first (which makes sense).

Is there a way to implement the drill down in the reportRequests so that I retrieve all data? If not, what would be the best way to get all data? Running the report request once with the custom dimensions and one without?

Thanks!

P.S. I found some other answers here about this issue but all of them are quite old and they don't mention the UI so I'm not sure if some things have changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you do the same with the API as with the UI (putting the customdimension last).As I understand you, you use the customdimension like a secondary dimension in your table view in the UI?
So why not try to use a your custom dimension like a secondary dimension in the api-request?

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE>'
VIEW_ID = '<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)
analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            
          'dateRanges': [
                          {
                              'startDate': '7daysAgo', 
                              'endDate': 'yesterday'
                          },
                         {
                             'startDate':  '14daysAgo',
                             'endDate': '8daysAgo'
                         }
                        ],
            
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'},],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:RegularDimension'},{'name': 'ga:CustomDimension'}],
          'samplingLevel':'LARGE'
            
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```